# How to get number of students per course in sql?

Tags: sql, count

So I have these 3 tables:

t_student which looks like this:

```
STUDENT_ID| FIRST_NAME  |LAST_NAME
-----------------------------------
1         |  Ivan       | Petrov
2         |  Ivan       | Ivanov
3         |  Georgi     | Georgiev
```

t_course which looks like this:

```
course_id |  NAME       |LECTURER_NAME
-----------------------------------
1         |  Basics     | Vasilev
2         |  Photography| Loyns
```

t_enrolment which looks like this:

```
enrolment_id|   student_fk  |course_fk | Avarage_grade 
-------------------------------------------------------
1           |  1            | 1        |
2           |  3            | 1        |
3           |  4            | 1        |
4           |  2            | 1        | 
5           |  1            | 2        | 5.50
6           |  2            | 2        | 5.40
7           |  5            | 2        | 6.00
```

I need to make 'select' statement and present the number of students per course. The result should be:

```
Count_students | Course_name
-----------------------------
4              | Basics
3              | Photography
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all courses from your course Table, join the enrolment table and group by your course id. With count() you can select the number of Students

```
    SELECT MAX(t_course.NAME) AS Course_name, COUNT(t_enrolment.student_fk) AS Count_students
    FROM t_course
    LEFT JOIN t_enrolment ON t_enrolment.course_fk = t_course.course_id
    GROUP BY t_course.course_id;
```

If you want to select the same student in one course only once (if more then one enrolment can happen) you can use COUNT(DISTINCT t_enrolment.student_fk)

**UPDATE**

To make it working not only in mySQL I added an aggregate function to the name column.

Depending on the SQL database you are using you will have to add quotes or backticks.

Comment: Question was how to group by course, so why not accept that two courses can be named identically?

Comment: Fine, but in every database except mysql your query will not execute because it has an error

Comment: Ok, removed quotes to make it work in other SQL databases. What's the best way to make quotes work in all SQL databases?

Comment: The problem is not the back ticks. The problem is you are not grouping by all non aggregated columns. The only way I think you will understand is if you visit http://SQLFiddle.com and select a database type other than mysql and try your query.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your homework?

```
select count(*) Count_students, c.name as course_name from t_enrolment e, t_course c group where e.course_fk = c.course_id  by c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a select statement with a join to the couse table (for the `Course_name`). Group by `'t_course'.name` to use the `COUNT(*)` function

this will work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count_students, c.NAME AS Course_name 
FROM t_enrolment e
JOIN course c
ON e.course_fk = c.course_id
GROUP BY c.NAME
```

**More information**

[Count function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/counting-rows.html)

[Group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/group-by-modifiers.html)

[Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/join.html)